# xml throwing NullPointer exception

Tags: android

Can anyone see why the following XML file should throw `NullPointerexception`?

If I remove all reference to the array `hrs_to_wait_value`, it is ok.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="hrs_to_wait_options">
<item>1 hour</item>
<item>2 hours</item>
<item>3 hours</item>
<item>4 hours</item>
<item>5 hours</item>
<item>6 hours</item>
<item>7 hours</item>
<item>8 hours</item>
<item>9 hours</item>
<item>10 hours</item>
<item>11 hours</item>
<item>12 hours</item>
<item>13 hours</item>
<item>14 hours</item>
<item>15 hours</item>
<item>16 hours</item>
<item>17 hours</item>
<item>18 hours</item>
<item>19 hours</item>
<item>20 hours</item>
</string-array>

<array name="hrs_to_wait_values">
<item>1</item>
<item>2</item>
<item>3</item>
<item>4</item>
<item>5</item>
<item>6</item>
<item>7</item>
<item>8</item>
<item>9</item>
<item>10</item>
<item>11</item>
<item>12</item>
<item>13</item>
<item>14</item>
<item>15</item>
<item>16</item>
<item>17</item>
<item>18</item>
<item>19</item>
<item>20</item>
</array>


</resources>
```

Comment: oh it stripped out the xml stuff!

Comment: You need to use the "code" icon to put your xml and make it visible to us. (icon with 101010 above the writing panel). Or add 4 spaces before each line

Comment: It's not your XML file that's doing it, where's your code?

Comment: XML doesn't throw exceptions.  Java does.  Show some code and a stacktrace.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not agree guys, this xml does throw an NPE if you try loading it in a spinner for instance...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe am I mistaken, but I think that your issue is caused indeed by your XML. You wrote this for the first array :

```
<string-array name="hrs_to_wait_options">
<item>1 hour</item>
<item>2 hours</item>
.
.
.
</string-array>
```

And, this for the 2nd :

```
<array name="hrs_to_wait_values">
<item>1</item>
<item>2</item>
.
.
.
</array>
```

And you actually don't have the "string-" in the name. As I assume that you are using this in some kind of spinner or something of the sort, you have to use string-arrays If i remember well. Try changing it to  this :

```
<string-array name="hrs_to_wait_values">
<item>1</item>
<item>2</item>
.
.
.
</string-array>
```

Comment: Thanks - changing to a string array stopped the exception.   I based the xml on an example in Reto Meier's book on Android 2 where he uses the string array for the data to be displayed by a list but an array for the corresponding values which are ints.  I can live with it though!  Thanks again.